# VLOOKUP, if item not found print "" and increment a cell's value by one

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

What I have so far:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$814,2,FALSE)) = TRUE, SUM($D$1,1), VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$814,2,FALSE))
```

So using `VLOOKUP`, if it isn't found in the table I want it to print `""` (nothing) and then increment cell D1 by 1 (this is sort of a not found counter I made). Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify your question: it sounds like you want D1 to contain a counter of all vlookups that are blank. The vlookup formula you supplied cannot both increment the counter AND return blank if not found. Instead of returning SUM($D$1), return "" as in:  IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$1:$F$814,2,FALSE)) = TRUE, "", VLOOKUP(A2,$E$1:$F$814,2,FALSE))  and have a formula in $d$1 which counts for non blank cells in the range which contains the vlookup formulas: +COUNTA(A4:A7) where a4.a7 all contain the vlookup()

Comment: Good comments mseifert, why not post as an answer? Which version of Excel are you using meiryo? In Excel 2007 or later versions you can use IFERROR to avoid repeating the VLOOKUP

Comment: Excel 2013. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: FYI, your formula could be greatly shortened with the use of `IFERROR`, it's like a combination of `IF` and `ISNA` that saves you from having to write the vlookup twice. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...), SUM(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is not very clear, I think that this will get you going.
This formula, checks the whole list and marks if the search item (2nd part of the formula) is found in the (expanding) list (first part of the formula). You could combine this with an IF statement:

`If(COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1)=1,"",COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1))`

Place the formula in Cell B1 (in this example) and drag down so that the formula in B2 looks like this: =COUNTIF(A$1:A2;A2)

[image]